# Proving $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Prove the distributive property for sets:
>
> $A \cup (B \cap C) =  (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

I'm not good with proofs but my understanding is that I have to prove 2 things:

(1)  $A \cup (B \cap C) \subset (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap C)$

(2)  $A \cap (B \cap C) \supset (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

This is what I have done so far:

Part (1)

If $x\in A$, then $x \in (A \cup B)$ and $x \in (A \cup C)$.

$\therefore x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap C)$

If $x \in (B \cap C)$ then $x \in (A  \cup B)$ and $x \in (A \cup C)$ because $x \in B$ and $x \in C$.

$\therefore x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap C)$

$\therefore A \cup (B \cap C) \subset (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

Part (2)

Now we have to prove the reverse inequality:  $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cap C)$.  Then $x \in A \cup B$ **and** $x \in (A \cup C)$

If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$

---

This is where I am up to.  I wanted to know whether my approach is correct and if I did part (1) correctly.  I'm stuck on part (2) and don't know how to proceed.  I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you!!

Comment: Alright I'm no math major but I put some stuff together below.  If anyone could verify I would appreciate it.  I just learned about the symbols $\land \lor$ now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You must first prove 2 cases:

(1)  $A \cap (B \cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

(2)  $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \subset A \cap (B \cup C)$

Note that in mathematics we use the following symbols:

$\cap=$ AND = $\land$

$\cup=$ OR = $\lor$

### **Case 1:  $A \cap (B \cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$**

Let $x \in A \cap (B \cup C) \implies x \in A \land x \in (B \cup C)$

$\implies x \in A \land \{ x \in B \lor x \in C \}$

$\implies \{ x \in A \land x \in B \} \lor\{ x \in A \land x \in C \} $

$\implies x \in (A \cap B) \lor x \in (A \cap C)$

$\implies x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

$\therefore x \in A \cap (B \cup C) \implies x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

$\therefore A \cap (B \cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

### **Case 2: $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \subset A \cap (B \cup C)$**

Let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \implies x \in (A \cap B) \lor x \in (A \cap C)$

$\implies \{x \in A \land x \in B \} \lor \{ x \in A \land x \in C \}$

$\implies x \in A \land \{ x \in B \lor x \in C\}$

$\implies x \in A \land \{B \cup C \}$

$\implies x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$

$\therefore x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \implies x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$

$\therefore (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \subset A \cap (B \cup C)$

---

$\therefore A \cup (B \cap C) =  (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

Comment: Why must we prove the case `A∩(B∪C)⊂(A∩B)∪(A∩C)` instead of proving the case `A∪(B∩C)⊂(A∪B)∩(A∪C)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = A \cap (B \cup C)$ and $Y = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

To show that $X=Y$, we must show that:

1. $X \subseteq Y$
2. $Y \subseteq X$

**Case 1:** $X \subseteq Y$

If $x \in X$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in (B \cup C)$

The latter implies that $x$ is a member of at least one of $B$ or $C$.

We will proceed from here in 3 cases:

**Case A:** $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$

We know from above that $x \in A$.

If $x \in B$ and $x \in A$, then $x \in (A \cap B)$.

If $x \in (A \cap B)$, then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = Y$, therefore $x \in Y$.

**Case B:** $x \notin B$ and $x \in C$

This is symmetric to Case A.

**Case C:** $x \in B$ and $x \in C$

This is simply an extension of Case A and Case B.

Therefore, if $x \in X$, then $x \in Y$, which implies $X \subseteq Y$.

**Case 2:** $Y \subseteq X$

If $y \in Y$, then $y$ is a member of at least one of $(A \cap B)$ or $(A \cap C)$.

Again, we have 3 cases:

**Case A:** $y \in (A \cap B)$ and $y \notin (A \cap C)$.

The former implies $y \in A$ and $y \in B$ by the definition of intersection.

If $y \in B$, then $y \in (B \cup C)$.

If $y \in A$ and $y \in (B \cup C)$, then $y \in (A \cap (B \cup C))$.

$(A \cap (B \cup C)) = X$, therefore $y \in X$.

**Case B:** $y \notin (A \cap B)$ and $y \in (A \cap C)$.

This is symmetric to Case A.

**Case C:** $y \in (A \cap B)$ and $y \in (A \cap C)$.

This is simply an extension of Case A and Case B.

Therefore, if $y \in Y$, then $y \in X$, which implies $Y \subseteq X$.

From Case 1 and Case 2, we have:

$X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$, therefore $X = Y$, which implies $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to do a calculational proof, starting at the most complex side, to calculate which elements are in $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$: for all $x$,
$$
\begin{align}
& x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\cap$; definition of $\cup$, twice"} \\
& (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in A \lor x \in C) \\
(*) \; \equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify by 'factoring out' $x \in A$, using the fact that $\lor$ distributes over $\land$"} \\
& x \in A \lor (x \in B \land x \in C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\cap$; definition of $\cup$"} \\
& x \in A \cup (B \cap C) \\
\end{align}
$$
Now by extensionality (i.e., equal sets have the same elements) it follows that $$(0) \;\;\; A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$$

Note how we didn't need to prove two separate $\subseteq$ cases.  Also note that the key step $(*)$ uses the logical law $$(1) \;\;\; P \lor (Q \land R) \;\equiv\; (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$$  We see that $(0)$ and $(1)$ have the same structure.  Since $(1)$ is in the logic domain, it is more generally useful than $(0)$, which is only applicable when dealing with sets.

Comment: that's a trick, not a real proof