# Proof of $A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to resit a calculus exam and for some reason set proofs were never my best friend...

Anyway, on a practice exam I encountered the following proof:

$$A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$$

When I draw a Venn-diagram it seems quite obvious but I couldn't manage to write the proof down properly.

If someone could help me, that'd be great!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389689/set-distributive-property-proof) is closely related and the answer is very similar.

Comment: For proofs like this, using the definition of set operations (which are mostly) and using rules of inference always worked for me.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435433/proof-of-a-capb-cup-c-a-cap-b-cupa-cap-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B\cup C$.

$x\in B\cup C\implies (x\in B$ or $x\in C)$.

So, $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)\implies x\in (A\cap B)$ or $ x\in (A\cap C)$

$\implies x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$

$\implies A\cap(B\cup C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$.

Similarly,

if $y\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C),$

$\implies y\in (A\cap B)$ or $y\in (A\cap C),$

$\implies y\in A$ and $y\in (B$ or $C)$

$\implies y\in A$ and $y\in (B \cup C)$

$\implies y\in A\cap (B \cup C)$.

Now, $A \subseteq  B$ and $B \subseteq  A \implies A=B$.

Comment: The inclusion you proved is not what the OP wanted. And then the reverse inclusion $A\cap(B\cup C)\supseteq (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$ is false.

Comment: @Ink, can you please substantiate the last statement?

Comment: @SumitBhowmick Consider $A = \{1, 2\}$, $B = C = \{1\}$.  Then $A \cap (B \cup C) = \{1\}$, while $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) = \{1, 2\}$.

Comment: @Ink, please have a look into the edited answer

Comment: It's correct now.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done by algebra or by a truth table.  In some cases there might be reasons why it would be necessary to use algebra.  But not in all.  Here's a truth table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x\in A & x\in B & x\in C & x\in A\cap(B\cup C) & x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C) \\
\hline
T & T & T & ? & ? \\
T & T & f & ? & ? \\
T & f & T & ? & ? \\
f & T & T & ? & ? \\
T & f & f & ? & ? \\
f & T & f & ? & ? \\
f & f & T & ? & ? \\
f & f & f & ? & ? \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
You need **(1)** to make sure all eight possible rows are there, **(2)** to fill in the blanks, and **(3)** to check carefully that the last two columns are identical.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: proofs by characteristic function :

for any $A \subset X$ define $1_A : X \to \{ 0,1\}$ by

$$1_A(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
1 & \mbox{if } x \in A \\
0 & \mbox{if } x \notin A \\
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}\right.$$
then we have

- $A= B \Leftrightarrow 1_A = 1_B$
- $1_{A \cap B}=1_A \cdot 1_B$
- $1_{A \cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_A \cdot 1_B$

here we want prove$$ A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C) \iff 1_{A\cap(B\cup C)} = 1_{(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)}$$
$\color{red}{proof:}$

> 1.$$ \large{1_{A\cap(B\cup C)}= 1_{A} 1_{B\cup C}=(1_{A} (1_B+1_C-1_B \cdot 1_C))=1_{A} 1_B+1_{A} 1_C-1_{A} \cdot1_B \cdot 1_C}$$
> 2.$$\large{1_{(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)}=1_{(A\cap B)}+1_{(A\cap C)}-1_{(A\cap B)}\cdot1_{(A\cap C)}=1_{A} 1_B+1_{A} 1_C-1_{A} \cdot1_B \cdot 1_C}$$

Answer (score 4):

First of all, two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if and only if $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

So, just use the fact that $x\in B\cup C$ if and only if $x\in B$ or $x\in C$ (or both).

Also, just use the fact that $x\in B\cap C$ if and only if $x\in B$ and $x\in C$.

Then, show that those two inclusions hold.

Comment: @Sigue, use $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, why?

Comment: because, a proper subset can not be equal to the respective super set

Comment: But $\subset$ is not a symbol for proper subset, in my opinion. $A\subset B$ means $\forall x(x\in A\to x\in B)$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: $\subset$ is also valid and popular notation of subset(not necessarily proper)

Comment: For reasons such as this silly argument, I use $\subsetneq$ to denote a proper subset.

Answer (score 4):

You have to show that a point is in the left side if and only if it is in the right side.

Take $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$. It means that 
$$ x\in A\wedge(x\in B\vee x\in C)$$
To show that it is contained in the right side, assume that $x$ is not in $A\cap B$, so it is not in both $A$ and $B$. But we know that it is in $A$, so what does this imply for $B$?. Can you show that in this case $x$ must be in $A\cap C$?

For the reverse inclusion you can use the equivalences
$$X\cup Y\subseteq Z \text{ if and only if }X\subseteq Z\text{ and }Y\subseteq Z$$
as well as
$$X\subseteq Y\cap Z \text{ if and only if } X\subseteq Y\text{ and }X\subseteq Z$$
for aarbitrary sets $X,Y,Z$. It would be a good exercise to try the reverse inclusion only using these equivalences and the properties $X\cap Y\subseteq Y$ and $X\subseteq X\cup Y$ and without considering elements.