# How do you write, $(A∩B)\setminus (A∩C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you write, $(A\cap B)\setminus (A\cap C)$. I know $(A \cap B) = \{x: x \in A$ and $x \in B\}$, and $(A \setminus B) = \{x: x \in A$ and $x \not \in B)\}$, but I don't know how to combine these facts into one.

Comment: Hint: $A \backslash B=A\cap B^c$

Answer (score 2):

You are taking $A\cap B$ and excluding something from it. Anything you exclude from $A\cap B$ is automatically in $A$. So at that point, writing that you are excluding $A\cap C$ is a little redundant. You can just say you are excluding $C$. So you have the same thing as $$(A\cap B)\setminus C$$ It's hard to imagine anything simpler exists, since this references the three sets involved each precisely once. This is the same as $$A\cap(B\setminus C)$$ so you could just write $$A\cap B\setminus C$$

If you want set-builder notation, this is $$\{x\mid x\in A \text{ and } x\in B \text{ and } x\not\in C\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$, and apply DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

Picture it in words. You want to write that the element has to be in the intersection of A and B but not in the intersection of A and C.  From here it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Its a two step:

$$\begin{align}(A\cap B)\setminus(A\cap C) & = \{x \mid x\in (A\cap B)\wedge x\notin(A\cap C)\} \\[1ex] & = \{x\mid (x\in A\wedge x\in B)\wedge (x\notin A\vee x\notin C)\}\end{align}$$

From here you can use distribution to simplify.

---

Because: $$\begin{align}x\notin(A\cap C) & = x\in(A^\complement \cup C^\complement) \\ & = x\in A^\complement \;\vee\; x\in C^\complement \\ & = x\notin A \;\vee\; x\notin C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that there's no logical symbol for "but not", but that is solved by the fact that $X\setminus Y = X \cap \overline{Y}$. So it's just to rewrite:

$$(A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap \overline{(A \cap C)}$$

And then write the condition for membership:

$$(x \in A \land x\in B) \land\neg( x\in A \land x\in C )$$

This of course could be rewritten using De Morgan rules:

$$x \in A \land x\in B \land (\neg (x\in A) \lor \neg(x\in C))$$

$$x \in A \land x\in B \land (x\notin A \lor x\notin C)$$

Then using the distributive law:

$$(x \in A \land x\in B \land x\notin A) \lor x (\in A \land x\in B \land x\notin C)$$

where the first term is a contradiction and can be dropped:

$$x\in A \land x\in B \land x\notin C$$

Answer (score -1):

You can learn a few simple laws of set theory in one week and use them always.

$(A\cap B)\setminus (A\cap C)=[\color{green}{\text{by Boby's comment}}]$

$(A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)^c=$ [[**by De Morgan's laws**]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)
$\color{red}{(A\cap B)}\cap (A^c\cup C^c)=$ [[**by this question**]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435433/proof-of-a-capb-cup-c-a-cap-b-cupa-cap-c)

$(\color{red}{A\cap B}\cap A^c)\cup (\color{red}{A\cap B}\cap C^c)=$

$(A\cap B\cap C^c)=[\color{green}{\text{by Boby's comment}}]$

$(A\cap B)\setminus C$

Comment: down-vote?!!!!!!