# prove $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$ with algebra of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

A friend of mine had asked me to prove this statement with algebra of sets. So at first I provided him with this answer:

[Proof of $A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435433/proof-of-a-capb-cup-c-a-cap-b-cupa-cap-c)

but the problem is that this is not the kind of solution he wants,he wants this to be proved  using algebra of set but as I read in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets this statement is a fundamental properties of set algebra and I'm not sure if we can prove this using set algebra.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, this is an axiom for Boolean algebras, and thus its proof is trivial in that setting. But the motivation of this axiom is exactly that it holds for sets.

Comment: Either you deduce it from the logical properties of union and intersection (using double inclusion) so via pure set theory, or you assume these "laws" as an axiom of the structure (a Boolean algebra) and just accept that subsets of a set form a Boolean algebra and thus obey these laws. It depends on what you consider your most basic structure... I'd go for the set theory proof.

Comment: so am I getting this right? the only way to prove this is to use the definition of union and intersection. and because this statement is too fundamental we can not use set algebra right?

Comment: See theorem 2.17 (iii) in http://math.sharif.edu/faculties/uploads/safdari/Foundations-of-Math.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's very tedious, but using the basic definitions of membership, union and intersection:

$$x\in A \iff \{x|x\in A\}$$

$$x\in (A\cup B) \iff \{x|x\in A \lor x\in B\}$$

$$x\in (A\cap B) \iff \{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}$$

your left hand side becomes

$$A \cap (B\cup C) = \{\{x|x\in A\} \land \{x|x\in B \lor x\in C\}\}$$

$$A \cap (B\cup C) = \{x|x\in A\land (x\in B \lor x\in C)\}$$

$\lor$ distributes, so

$$ = \{x|(x\in A \lor x\in B) \land (x\in A \lor x\in C)\}$$

$$ = \{(A\cup B) \land (B\cup C)\}$$

$$ = (A\cup B) \cap (B\cup C)$$