# Indicator Function Distributive Property Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is my first post(:

I'm trying to understand how to prove the distributive property using the indicator function.  I have made the truth tables and understand how this is proved using set notation as in this question: [Set Distributive Property Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389689/set-distributive-property-proof)
But I cant seem to understand how to write this using indicator function notation.

$\mathbb{A}$ is a proposition about elements $x \in X$ and we put the corresponding set $A = \{x \ \in X: \mathbb{A}(x)\}$.

For each $x \in X$ and $A \subset X$ define the **indicator function of the set** A by

\[1_A (x) := \begin{cases} 
1 & if \; x \in A \\ 
0 & if \; x \notin A 
\end{cases}
\]
Further, the "and" and "or" of this are given by:

$ (1_A \wedge 1_B)(x) = 1_A(x) \cdot 1_B(x) = 1_A \cdot 1_B $

$ (1_A \vee 1_B)(x) = 1_A(x) + 1_B(x) - 1_A(x) \cdot 1_B(x) = 1_A + 1_B - 1_A \cdot 1_B$

Prove:

$ (\mathbb{A} \vee (\mathbb{B} \wedge \mathbb{C})) \iff ((\mathbb{A} \vee \mathbb{B}) \wedge (\mathbb{A} \vee \mathbb{C})) $

Writing the left side in indicator function notation I think it should be:
$ 1_A \vee (1_B \wedge 1_C)(x) = 1_A \vee ( 1_B \cdot 1_C ) = 1_A + (1_B \cdot 1_C) - 1_A \cdot (1_B \cdot 1_C) $

However, the textbook says it should be: $ 1_A \cdot (1_B + 1_C - 1_B \cdot 1_C) $
Which looks like the reverse order of what I think, so I'm stuck here.

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct; the book’s expression is the indicator function corresponding to $\Bbb A\land(\Bbb B\lor\Bbb C)$, not to $\Bbb A\lor(\Bbb B\land\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Oh, okay great thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still stuck.  I've tried reworking this starting with $ 1_A + 1_B \cdot 1_C - 1_A \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C $ but can't get it into the form of the right side: $ 1_A \cdot 1_B + 1_A \cdot 1_C - 1_A \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C $  Or do I look at $ 1_A + 1_B \cdot 1_C - 1_A \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C \leq 1_A \cdot 1_B + 1_A \cdot 1_C - 1_A \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C $ and consider all the cases when each may equal 1 or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s generally easiest to start with the more complicated expression, which in this case is the indicator function corresponding to the righthand side,

$$(1_A+1_B-1_A\cdot 1_B)\cdot(1_A+1_C-1_A\cdot 1_C)\;.$$

If you multiply this out, you get

$$\begin{align*}
1_A\cdot(1_A&+1_C-1_A\cdot 1_C)+1_B\cdot(1_A+1_C-1_A\cdot 1_C)-1_A\cdot 1_B\cdot(1_A+1_C-1_A\cdot 1_C)\\
&=(1_A+\color{brown}{1_A\cdot 1_C}-\color{brown}{1_A\cdot 1_C})+(\color{blue}{1_A\cdot 1_B}+1_B\cdot 1_C-1_A\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_C)\\
&\qquad-(\color{blue}{1_A\cdot 1_B}+\color{green}{1_A\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_C}-\color{green}{1_A\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_C})\\
&=1_A+1_B\cdot 1_C-1_A\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_C\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much; again!  ^_^

Comment: @Sunhwa: My pleasure. (I’d normally give a hint rather than a complete answer, but when you’re just starting, a fully worked out example can be very helpful.)

Comment: The indicator function is also known as the characteristic function.