# Show $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show the following: $$A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$$
So let's first show that $A\cup(B\cap C)\subseteq(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$.

Let $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)$

1st case: $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in(A\cup B)\land x\in(A\cup C)\Rightarrow x\in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$

2nd case: $x\in B\cap C\iff x\in B\land x\in C\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B\land x\in A\cup C\Rightarrow x\in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$

Now we have to show that $(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)\subseteq A\cup(B\cap C).$

Let $x\in(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B\land x\in A\cup C\\\iff(x\in A\lor x\in B)\land (x\in A\lor x\in C)$.

I don't know how to go from here. There're so many things going on in that last statement. Is the first part of my solution correct? Can someone solve it without looking at different cases as I did? Thank you!

Comment: Check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389689/proving-a-cup-b-cap-c-a-cup-b-cap-a-cup-c

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, well I think I've clearly stated what confuses me and why I don't know how to continue. I am not just looking for a solution.

Comment: Hmm... your 3rd question was "Can someone solve it without looking at different cases as I did?". That post answers it And it also answers you 1st question about "how to go from here". As for your 2nd  question the answer is yes.

Comment: @AnneBauval, yeah I mean if there is a solution which doesn’t look at cases, as I think it would be better.

Comment: The first part is correct. For the second part, consider two cases: (1) $x\in A$: (2) $x\not\in A$.

Comment: Does this answer your first and third question? [Proving $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389689/proving-a-cup-b-cap-c-a-cup-b-cap-a-cup-c) See also [Proof of $A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435433). As for the second one, it has been answered in comments: yes, your first part is correct.

Comment: As for proving it without cases, you could use the fact that $\vee$ distributes over $\wedge$. But this just substitutes $\vee$ for $\cup$ and $\wedge$ for $\cap$.  You could prove the formula of propositional logic with truth tables, but in a way this is also just a proof by cases.

Answer (score 0):

$(x \in A\ \lor\ x \in\ B) \land\ (x \in A\ \lor\ x \in\ C) $

case 1: $x \in A \implies x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$

case 2: $x \notin A$. But since  $x \in A\ \lor\ x \in\ B$, then $x \in B$.

similarly, you can prove that $x\in C$. Therefore, $x\in (B\cap C) \implies x\in A \cup (B\cap C) $